# nginx server_name not prioritized

Tags: nginx

Why won't my configuration route to the specific `server_name` when it's specified?

Part of my config:

```
server
{
  listen      443 ssl;
  server_name foo-bar.example.com;

  include includes/http/server/ssl.conf;

  location /
  {
    #...
  }
}

server
{
  listen 80   default_server;
  listen 162  default_server;
  listen 443  default_server;
  listen 465  default_server;
  listen 3306 default_server;
  listen 9200 default_server;

  return 444;
}
```

However, going to the domain `foo-bar.example.com` returns the `444` status. When I remove the last block, it works as expected.

**I tried** adding:

- `server_name ""`
- `server_name _`

...in the last block without success.

---

The priorities defined on this page: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> - exact name
> - longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g.    “*.example.org”
> - longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g.    “mail.*”
> - first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in    a configuration file)

...tells me that what I do should work, imo.

Answer (score 3):

When looking in the `error.log`, located in `/var/log/nginx/`, I found `no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking`

So adding a new block:

```
server
{
  listen 443 default_server;
  include includes/http/server/ssl.conf;
  return 444;
}
```

...while removing the `listen 443 default_server` from the former block, did the trick...

---

**includes/http/server/ssl.conf**

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/crt.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/key.key;
```

Comment: @Drifter104 why don't you just edit it, or simply add a comment suggestion improvements? The answer is correct! Now it's more complete....

Comment: The overall parts were there but not in a way that someone looking for a solution to a similar problem could of found all that easy to put together. Now however it is a complete answer and I have reversed the downvote accordingly.